# Trying to count the number of words in a corpus and append the count as a column to the dataset

Tags: text, nlp

I'm working on a text project and I need to count up the occurrence of specific words per conversation. I have a for loop which will count the occurrence for a row but I'm struggling to append the results as columns to the data set.

```
This is the loop I am using: 

# Initializie score counters for each area
meet = 0
location = 0
day = 0
time = 0
transfer = 0
total = 0

# Create an empty list where the scores will be stored
scores = []


# Obtain the scores for each area

for area in terms.keys():
 
if area == 'Meet':
    for word in terms[area]:
        if word in text:
            meet +=1
    scores.append(meet)
    
elif area == 'Location':
    for word in terms[area]:
        if word in text:
            location +=1
    scores.append(location)
    
elif area == 'Day':
    for word in terms[area]:
        if word in text:
            day +=1
    scores.append(day)
    
elif area == 'Time':
    for word in terms[area]:
        if word in text:
            time +=1
    scores.append(time)

elif area == 'Total':
    for word in terms[area]:
        if word in text:
            total +=1
    scores.append(total)
          
else:
    for word in terms[area]:
        if word in text:
            transfer +=1
    scores.append(transfer)
```

It is referencing a dictionary and I'm working with a basic df of 1000 rows x 5 columns which looks like this:

```
_id message                               sum   Target variable word_count
0   5555555 Hello there fellow Went people  6   0                 852
```

The sum and word count are irrelevant right now.

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
df['Meet_word'] = df['message'].map(lambda x: x.count("meet"))
```

Any advice is really appreciated!